# How to stop Chrome from blocking .zip files I generate?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, download, zip

I have a web project (in TypeScript) that generates files and then allows you to package them them into a `.zip` file using the [jsZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) library, and then the [file-saver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) library to actually save/download the file.

Here is how I create the zip and save it

```ts
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
import * as fileSaver from 'file-saver';

downloadZipFile(): void {
  const zip = new JSZip();

  for (const outputFile of this.outputFileList) {
    zip.file(outputFile.fileName, new File([outputFile.outputContent], outputFile.fileName));
  }

  //Generate the zip file contents
  zip
    .generateAsync({type: 'blob'})
    .then((zipContent: Blob) => {
      fileSaver.saveAs(zipContent, `LyricConverter (${this.outputFileList.length} files).zip`);
    });
}
```

This has worked fine for me in the past, and currently works fine locally.  However I recently purchased a domain name for my project, and when I attempt to download files from there Chrome blocks the download showing this message:

[image: blocked chrome download]

I have seen plenty of [articles](https://www.howtogeek.com/785997/how-to-stop-google-chrome-from-blocking-downloads/) and [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1410783/how-to-disable-chrome-download-blocking-feature) online about how to turn this Chrome feature off, but how can I just get this to work on my site for Chrome users?

Is Chrome looking for something on a site to mark it as "safe"? Could it be that my domain was only recently purchased, or maybe it requires an HTTPS site? Does anyone have more information of a solution for this?

Comment: Who comes up with these nonsense "features"? How on Earth is .zip not "commonly downloaded" and why would it be dangerous? If they're so worried about people downloading executables, might as well shut down the whole internet...

Comment: I know, I was very surprised to see this since zip is such a common format. My only other guess is that they can tell it was a generated file and not a HTTP request for a "real" file.

Comment: I mean, most of the time software you download cannot just disable the antivirus software or sneak past it; it's even harder this way (I think it's impossible).

Comment: ok, that's good news then!  thank you! I don't have a lot of traffic anyway, and there is a workaround for now.  So I'll check back in a week and see if it changes.  Still a bit odd though.

Comment: @code Just wanted to update you. It totally works now.  That was the issue.  Thanks!